# Loading a new view before the old one iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk

Probably just a simple question, but ive been building a little puzzle game and no decided i could do with a menu for it. Ive created the menu no problem i just cant get it to show before the puzzle. Ive tried changing the code in the appdelegate but its not liking it.

slider appdelegate.h

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class SliderViewController;
@class MainMenu;

@interface SliderAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    MainMenu *viewController1;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet SliderViewController *viewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MainMenu *viewController1;
@end
```

Slider appdelegate.m

```
#import "SliderAppDelegate.h"
#import "SliderViewController.h"

@implementation SliderAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize viewController;
@synthesize viewController1;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
    [self.window addSubview:viewController1.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

But doing that throws out an error:

> error: request for member 'view' in
>   something not a structure or union

I know its probably a stupid question but could anyone help please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import that class and make alloc the object first see this

Slider appdelegate.m

```
#import "SliderAppDelegate.h"
#import "SliderViewController.h"
#import "MainMenu.h"//change here

@implementation SliderAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize viewController;
@synthesize viewController1;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

   viewController = [[[MainMenu alloc] initWithNibName@"MainMenu" bundle:nil] autorelease]; // and here
    [self.window addSubview:viewController1.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Cheers for that, slight problem though it just loads a blank white screen not the screen with all the buttons on.